# how to assign URLs in bootstrap TbMenu in Yii?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, yii

this is my first touch with bootstrap, I want to use `TbMenu` widget which is similar to `CMenu`, but I am facing a problem with the URLs, here is my code:

```
 $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbMenu', array(
    'type'=>'tabs', // '', 'tabs', 'pills' (or 'list')
    'stacked'=>false, // whether this is a stacked menu
    'items'=>array(
        array('label'=>'home', 'url'=>'site/index'),
    ),
));
```

I want to put URL for the index page, which is found in the directory `protected/views/site/index.php` and it should be rendered by the `actionIndex` of the controller `siteController`, but when I click the tab an error occurred:

`The requested URL /Patra/site/index was not found on this server.`

so how I can put a URL for the index page in `TbMenu` ??

Comment: have you added .htaccess file in the place where index.php exist ?

Comment: @ramamoorthy_villi yes its built-in by the framework

Comment: @ramamoorthy_villi I want to use it in the widget

Comment: can you post your folder structure ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `'url'=>'site/index'` with `'url'=>array('site/index')`

Here is your code should be

```
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbMenu', array(
    'type'=>'tabs', // '', 'tabs', 'pills' (or 'list')
    'stacked'=>false, // whether this is a stacked menu
    'items'=>array(
        array('label'=>'home', 'url'=>array('site/index')),
    ),
));
```